# How to internationalize a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, localization

I maintain a product's Facebook Page in English, but many of the customers are Japanese, so I would like to provide a Japanese version of the page.

What is the best way to do so?

I hope there is an alternative to creating a separate page.

Answer (score 3):

When posting to FB you can click on Public button (before you hit share) and then Location/ Language and then choose the Japan as country when posting just for them.

Comment: +1 Great! I will do this for wall posts. Now if only I could do the same for About and Description...

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just localize you app.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Almost all dev frameworks themself provide support for localization besides the Facebook API.

Comment: I might not be understanding something, but it is not an app, I did not develop anything, just a plain facebook product page, I just filled a few fields like product name and description. The page is about an Android app, I will change it to "product" in the question to avoid misunderstandings.